# Classifying stack for finite flat group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, algebraic-stacks

Let $G$ be a finite flat non-smooth group scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$, for example, $G$ can be $\operatorname{Spec}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p[t]/(t^p))$. Then the classifying stack $\mathcal{X}:=BG$ is a smooth algebraic stack over $k$, so the diagonal of this stack is also smooth. However, by some computation, the stabilizer group scheme of a point $x: \operatorname{Spec}(k)\to \mathcal{X}$ is $G$, which is a base change of the smooth morphism $\triangle:\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{X}\times_k \mathcal{X}$ along $x: \operatorname{Spec}(k)\to \mathcal{X}$, but $G$ is not smooth.

Question: which statement(s) in the above paragraph is wrong?

Comment: The stack is not smooth.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar actually it is! See \[Tag [0DLS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DLS)\]. But I don't see why the diagonal of a smooth stack must be smooth — this already fails for smooth schemes, doesn't it?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I think you are right. For a geometrically connected variety $X$, the diagonal is a closed embedding. If it is smooth, it is in particular open. Then it violates the connectedness of $X\times X$. It is just a little counter-intuitive that closed immersion of smooth subscheme into a smooth scheme isn't always smooth.

Comment: There exist smooth varieties over fields of positive characteristic with non-reduced automorphism group schemes.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes, of course!

Comment: @user837898 I don't get the argument (yet). What if $X=\mathrm{Spec}$ $k$ ? Then the diagonal is smooth.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Sorry, I should have included the assumption that the diagonal morphism is not surjective.

Comment: The diagonal of a morphism of schemes $f \colon X \to Y$ is a locally closed immersion, so it is smooth if and only if it is an open immersion, i.e. $f$ is unramified.